factual error in the book ' The Formal Semantics of Programming Languages: An Introduction ' by Glynn Winskel
is there any official or unofficial site dedicated to errata on this book ?
This book was published in 1993 and is still prominent in the subject it discusses. No other editions ,  only one edition. And i believe i have found a factual error, a misinformation sort of( if i am choosing my words correctly ), in this book.
But the error itself, atleast to me, seems so trivial that it should have been caught by many readers before me, yet the copy i got from the web still has that error. So i presume some sort of errata already exists on this book.
